# Need PIVOT or CASE solution for converting columns to rows (NON-Dynamic if possible)

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, case

So I have a table that has data such as this:

```
 SCHD_ID | INST_ID |
|---------|---------|
|    1001 |    Mike |
|    1001 |     Ted |
|    1001 |   Chris |
|    1002 |    Jill |
|    1002 |   Jamie |
|    1003 |    Brad |
|    1003 |    Carl |
|    1003 |    Drew |
|    1003 |    Nick |
```

I need to come up with a query to display the data like below:

```
|SCHD_ID  | INST 1 | INST 2 | INST 3 |
|---------|--------|--------|--------|
| 1001    | Mike   | Ted    | Chris  |
| 1002    | Jill   | Jamie  | Null   |
| 1003    | Brad   | Carl   | Drew   |
```

I have tried looking into all the pivot descriptions and some case examples but everything seems to use a common repeated value to pivot around.  This is one of those cases where the columns need to be dynamic, but only to a point.  I can drop off any data after the third instructor.  In the example above I did not put in a column for INST 4 for SCHD_ID 1003 even though in my data set example it existed.  Can adding in a restraint like this make it possible to come up with a non dynamic solution for the pivot/case statement?

Thanks for the help,
Dwayne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()` and conditional aggregation.  However, your data doesn't have an ordering column, so you cannot guarantee which three instructors you will get:

```
select schd_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then inst_id end) as inst1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then inst_id end) as inst2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then inst_id end) as inst3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by schd_id order by sched_id) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by SCHD_ID ;
```

If you have a priority ordering for choosing the instructors, then put the logic in the `order by` clause.